# Cannot click tabs after displaying list

Tags: android

When I run my app. I have 4 tabs on the bottom (its the way i created them). Each tab pressed will bring up a list of tran stations etc...( supposed to happen)

Now im just testing tab2 button and it does bring up the list but cannot click on any other tabs. I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
//imports removed for brevity

//Second tab activity with the list activity

public class SecondActivity extends ListActivity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static final String[] stops = new String[] {
        "Pelham Parkway", "Yankees Stadium"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tab_test, stops)
        );

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    ((TextView) view).getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

Tabs code section:

Yes. Here is my code for the tabs.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost .TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
   intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

   intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FourthActivity.class);
   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator("Fourth")
                  .setContent(intent);
   tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @daniel, please try to be careful when setting the title of your question.  The more accurate, the quicker a response will be sent.  Also try to format code so that it doesn't require a scroll box ;)

Comment: How are you creating the tabs? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I got it working the way I wanted it. I corrected my xml referencing to the relative workout. And switched my extending ListActivity just Activity using findbyid to point to my list. 
Spend the last couple of days getting it to work correctly.